# How do i save a new record with a foriegn key using entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have two models, Product and Review. The Product model contains a navigation property called Review as seen below:

```
Public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=False])
    public int ProductID {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=False)
    public ICollection<Reviews> {get; set;}
}
```

The the Review model:

```
public class Review
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `Action` `ViewResult` method for ProductDetails where it fetches all Products plus all the reviews which has the same `FK` ProductIDs as seen here below:

```
public ViewResult ProductDetails(int productId)
{
    Product product = repository.Products
        .Include(p => p.Reviews)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    return View(product);
}
```

Then there is a `View` Which contains very simple HTML elements you can see it below:

```
@model app.models.Product

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductName)

@foreach (var review in Model.Reviews)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Reviews", review)
}
```

Within above view I called for a partial view to render all reviews belong to that specific product. In the Partial view i have a form where the user can submit a review. I want the user to submit a review for the Product which the name is at the top of the view. I know i have to create an action for this but the only thing makes me uncomfortable with it is that i can't figure out how to get the `ProductID` of that specific Product.

**Edit:**
As per Stephen's answer I had to put the form Html elements into the main view which is ProducDetails and had put some scripts to call Json result to save data in the database.

**Controller method to save the Review:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateReview (Review review)
        {
            if (review.ReviewId == 0)
            {
                db.Reviews.Add(review);
            }
            else
            {
                Review dbEntry = db.Reviews.Find(review.ReviewId);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.ProductID = review.ProductID;
                    dbEntry.Name = review.Name;
                    dbEntry.Subject = review.Subject;
                    dbEntry.Body = review.Body;
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true);
        }
```

Comment: The model in the view is `Product` which contains its `ProductID` property so you know it. What problems are you having?

Comment: Yes right in the main view it's Product and in the Partial view its Reviews. Nope what is the problem?

Comment: Your comment is more confusing than question. As Stephen mentioned, you already have productId in the review object in partial view. If you post your review object from partial view ajax call, at server it will bind correctly as the productId is inside the review object. If you are still facing issue, show you partial view code and we can help further.

Comment: Sorry, but its not making sense, Your partial is rendering all existing reviews. Surely that partial does not contain a form for creating a new `Review` (if you had 10 existing reviews, you would have 10 forms for creating new reviews)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry for the previous comment as it was the result of misunderstanding. Well the form is to submit the review data but review data is shown like @html.displayfor(model => model.Body)

Comment: Edit your question to show the partial view. Using `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not create form controls that can be posted so its unclear what you trying to do. And are you wanting to have a form to create a new review for the `Product` or edit existing Reviews?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you were right, i get forms by the number of reviews made how can i do that it is really a headache.

Comment: @StephenMuecke did you get my question ? i need your help please.

Comment: Are you wanting to edit the existing reviews or just display existing reviews and have one form to create a new `Review` for the `Product`?

Comment: Nope i don't want to edit i just want display existing reviews and have a form to add a new review? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then the form should be in the main view, not the partial. I will add an answer shortly.

Comment: Yes you are right, Thanks can you do it with ajax as i don't want to refresh all the page after the review is submitted. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wanting to create a new `Review` for the `Product` so the form needs to be in the main view, not the partial. The following assumes you want to submit using ajax and update the list of existing reviews

```
@model app.models.Product
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductName)
// display existing reviews
<div id="reviews">
    @foreach (var review in Model.Reviews)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => review.Body)
    }
</div>
<h2>Create new Review</h2>
@Html.Partial("_NewReview", new Review(){ ProductID = Model.ProductID })
```

Where `_NewReview.cshtml` is

```
@model Review
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subject)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)
    <input id="create" type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

and delete the `_Reviews.cshtml` file

Then in the main view, add the following script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Review")';
var reviews = $('#reviews');
var form = $('form');
$('#create').click(function() {
    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(response) {
        if (response) {
            reviews.append($('#Body').val()); // add the new Review to the existing reviews
            form.get(0).reset(); // reset the form controls
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {
        // oops
    });
    return false; // cancel the default submit
});
```

which will submit to (in `ReviewController`)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(Review model)
{
    // Save the model
    return Json(true); // return something to indicate success
}
```

Comment: Dear Stephen, i wasn't able to save the product ID of the Product table into the Review Table where can i get it from. Running your code with an json result gives me the error of conflicting the PK. How to solve that?

Comment: That could be an issue with routing. I have edited the answer to add the `ProjectID` value as a hidden input.

Comment: Stephen, now i am not getting the error it seems everything going fine but i see no record added to the database and i also don't get a new review in my review list. I put a break point on the json result in the controller but it seems that the script doesn't call the json result, any idea what would be the problem?

Comment: You have not shown any of the code your using to save the record so I cant guess. Best to ask a new question with the relevant code.

Comment: Stephen I have updated my question and added the controller method for saving the Review at end of the question. Would you please advise me accordingly? Thanks

Comment: You need to ask a **new** question (your cant just keep adding new questions to your existing question). But what you have shown should work fine although its unclear why you have an `if` statement - the `ReviewId` property will always be `0` (your creating a new review, not editing existing ones). Put a breakpoint on your controller and check that all the properties of `Review` are being populated correctly.

Comment: Stephen alright i asked a new question and got the answer how to pass the ProductID, but in your answer how could i place that script in main view while the form residing in the partial? i did put the script on the main page but when i click on create but nothing happens but when i put in the partial everything works just fine. this question is relevant to your answer :)

Comment: I saw your other question and its not clear what your doing or what your having trouble with. In the first code snippet of my answer the code is `@Html.Partial("_NewReview", new Review(){ ProductID = Model.ProductID })` which passes the `ProductID` to the partial which puts its value in a hidden input and will therefore be posted to the `Create(Review model)` method. The script must be in the main page, not the partial and it works fine as I have shown it so perhaps you have made a typo. In any case, use your browser tools to debug the script and check what errors your getting.

Comment: The script works fine in the _CreateReview partial but not within the main view, What could be the cause?

Comment: No idea. Scripts should not be in partials (only the main view or the layout). Have you put the script at the bottom of the page (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag? - it should be, or else wrapped in `$(document).ready() { .... }`. Note I have tested it an its works fine (but I do notice you have changes the names of a few things so perhaps you have a typo)

Comment: yes i included it just before the </body> tag and wrapped it in <script></script> not the document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

As i can imagine ProductId is unique 
In Your Partial View you can Write your code inside **Ajax.BeginForm**

```
@model Review
@Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { productId = Model.ProductId }, @*AjaxOptions Attribute*@)
{
     Review Fields here
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Review"/>
}
```

Comment: I am taking it as you want submit button in each row

Comment: Can't use this in my partial as the form is repeated as many as the number of reviews per product.

Comment: Then the ProductId is same for every review right??

Comment: So for one product you are displaying diff. reviews. And you are giving the current user an option to add review.

Answer (score -1):

To get the `ProductID`, you have add the `ForeignKey` of the `Product Table` in the `Review Table`.

```
public class Review
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    publiv virtual Product {get;set;}
}
```

hope this helps